# Injecting application level dependency into node module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dependency-injection, next.js

I'm trying to create package from higher order components that are currently in application.

The issue is that in some of those components application routes are being used ( through helper that imports all the routes and returns url based on route name ).

I have no idea how to inject those routes to my module from app level.

For example in Symfony ( PHP ) this issue would be fairly simple, due to dependency injection. But with imports inside each file I'm really lost here.

I'm using NextJS and here is code sample ( I would love to inject those routes instead of directly importing them ):

```
import { routes } from "../../routes";

export default (routeName, params) =>
  routes.find(route => route.name === routeName).toPath(params);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you building? What framework are you using? Can you provide example code?

Comment: fixed. Also I don't believe that what I'm building or framework make any difference. It's general node.js issue.

Comment: Why not do: `export default routes => (routeName, params) =>`?

Comment: I'm using this function directly in other HOC. It's like `getUrl('some-path-name')`.
So how am I supposed to add those routes then?

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own dependency injection module. 
Using NodeJs it's fairly simple to do.

This [one](https://gitlab.com/archiotect) for instance.